# How can I create an images loop?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code where after the 5th frame it stop for now because otherwise it will continue to count. But I am interested if there is a way to create a loop as if it reach the 5th frame to start from over and over again or to set how many loops.

```
var img, i = 1;
div = document.getElementById('foo');
img = new Image();
    div.appendChild(img);
    img.src = 'frames/frame_' + i + '.jpg';
    img.id = "top";

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    i++;

    var element = document.getElementById("top");
element.outerHTML = "";
delete element;

    if(i > 5) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
        img = new Image();
        div.appendChild(img);
        img.src = 'frames/frame_' + i + '.jpg';
        img.id = "top";
    }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Please clarify your problem. Now it's unclear what you want.

Comment: you can use `i=(i%5)+1`

Comment: I want to loop the images. Now I am loading the images and fade them. But when I reach the 5th image the fade will stop. And I want to continue from the first image

Comment: just set i to zero when it reaches 5 to restart the loop. To make it loop for a few times just set another counter that adds 1 when the one loop is finished